# Regex: This range OR that range

Tags: regex, range

So I am trying match a certain postcode range:

CB1 *, CB2 *, CB3 *, CB4 *, CB5 *, CB21 *, CB22 *, CB23 *, CB24 *, CB25 *

So I am trying to use range 1-5 OR 21-25.

This is my current regex:

`^[CBcb].([1-5]|[21-25]).+$`

I want to make sure the post code parts contains the following

`[CB OR cb],[1-5 OR 21-25] and [Any combination]`

Have a tinker: https://regex101.com/r/aP9uG3/2

How do you do you specify two ranges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the patterns are the same and it is just the `2` that may or may not occur, you can say something like:

```
CB2?[1-5]      # add ^ and $ if required
```

If you want to specify two ranges, you can always group them with parentheses `common_pattern(pattern1|pattern2)`.

Comment: Thanks, (and to everyone) else that came up with the solution.Just a quick question. The solution matches any cb[12345] (which I know understand). I want it pass for cb1, cb2, cb3, cb4, cb5 also for cb21. cb22, cb23, cb23, cb24, cb25 but fail for any other combination (i.e cb20, cb 32). Is this possible?

Comment: @Kal yes it is, if you use `^` and `$` to match the beginning and the end of the string. For example, `^CB2?[1-5]$` will not match neither cb20, nor cbxx, nor...

Answer (score 1):

`^cb2?[1-5].+$` and use the [`i` flag](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) as well.

The first error was that you were only matching one character from the list `[cbCB]`. The second is that there's a strange `.` in the middle. And the third is that you do not specify a range of numbers, but a range of characters. `21` is not a character, it is a sequence of characters. A range of characters to get all possible (integer) numbers would be `[0-9]*`. What you want is an optional `2` followed by a character from the range [1-5].

You should read up on what lists and ranges are and mean in Regular Expressions because you misused both of them! Eeryone makes mistakes obviously, but this is one of the basics you should get a hang of.

Answer (score 1):

Your Regex pattern:

```
^[CBcb].([1-5]|[21-25]).+$
```

is being interpreted as:

```
^[CBcb].([12345]|[2125]).+$
```

You need:

```
^CB2?[1-5].+'
```

here `?` means zero or one match of the preceding token, `2` in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Having characters inside `[]` makes it a character class. This means that in matches any character inside the brackets (unless it's negated). It doesn't understand numbers, but characters.

If you want to match `CB` or `cb`, you separate them by `|` like `CB|cb`. Or even better - make your regex case independent. This is done in different ways in different regex flavors. In javascript for example, attach the character `i` to the regex: `/cb/i`.

As for the rest of the pattern, if 1-5 and 20-25 is literally what you want, matching 1-5 is done with a character class (which you now are familiar with ;) like `[1-5]` meaning match any character in the ASCII range between the characters 1 and 5 inclusive.

Make the preceding `2` optional, and your regex looks like this

```
CB2?[1-5]
```

It matches your postcode and without a terminating `$`, it allows for your `[Any combination]`.

Hope this helps.

Regards